# django newbie - collecting data for multiple model instances in a single form

Tags: django, django-forms

Django Newbie working on a form to collect information for a carpool app.  In this form, a family is specifying which "legs" of a carpool for which their child needs a ride.  The Leg model looks like this:

```
class Leg(models.Model):
  drive_date = models.DateField()
  startpoint = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  endpoint = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  start_time = models.TimeField()
  riders = models.ManyToManyField(Rider, blank=True)
  drivers = models.ManyToManyField(Driver, blank=True)
  carpool = models.ForeignKey(Carpool)
```

A unique form will be generated for each rider. The form will look like this:  For each leg in a carpool, it will have actual uneditable data for the drive_date, startpoint, start_time (this information is already known).  Then they'll have a checkbox to indicate whether or not the rider needs a ride for that leg or not.  If the box is checked, that rider gets added to that leg when the form is submitted.

I've looked into model formsets, and at some other methods for creating "dynamic" django forms, but having a hard time making anything work.  Any advice on the best approach to show all the legs of a carpool on the same form, and include the rider checkbox, is much appreciated.  if there's already a good example of something like this, I'd sincerely appreciate a pointer to it.

Thanks!

Comment: Firstly, formsets are the right way to do this: exactly what problems are you having? And secondly, you must accept some answers to previous questions, otherwise I and others won't feel motivated to answer this one.

Comment: Sorry - wasn't aware of the protocol.  Have accepted answers for my previous questions.  WHen I looked at formsets, it wasn't clear to me how to populate a formset with existing data.  In the examples I looked at, formsets were used to provide a few blanks that the end user would fill in.  thanks very much.   mike

Comment: I'm not clear how to pass in the initial values for all of the existing legs.  in the examples I've looked at, they are populating data on the fly, and only one record contains initial data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this instance, I gave up on forms and formsets and built custom templates from scratch